# Relacionamento Cake PHP - 3 Tabelas

Tags: php, cakephp, relacionamento

Tenho as seguintes 3 tabelas:

**Tabela Estado:**

```
id
nomeEstado
```

**Tabela Cidade:**

```
id
idEstado //(que busca da tabela estado)
nomeCidade
```

**Tabela Participante:**

```
id
Nome
idCidade
```

Agora quero colocar na página `Nome`, `Cidade` e `Estado`, mas não estou conseguindo. Só consigo `Nome` e `Cidade`, o `Estado` não busca.

Como fazer o relacionamento entre 3 tabelas?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, inclua o código que está usando, é só [edit] a pergunta. Confira o guia [ask] para mais detalhes.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Tente reformulá-la.

Comment: @Alessandro, na tabela Participantes eu coloquei `idCidade` sem o `_` para seguir a mesma nomenclatura das outras (estava id_Cidade, então padronizei) e no exemplo que postei tem toda a explicação e no último item a solução. Aproveite!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie três Models na pasta `app/Model` na sua aplicação **CakePHP**.

Observação: Nome da classe é o mesmo nome do arquivo, ou seja, `class Estado` gera um arquivo `Estado.php` e assim por diante. Não se esquece de estender (`extends`) do `AppModel`. Todos os relacionamentos seguiram o exemplo do [site do Framework CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

**1) Configurações do Model:**

- *$userTable* = nome da tabela
- *$primaryKey* = nome da chave primária.

**2) Relacionamentos:**

Só foram utilizados `$hasMany` que é 1 para muitos e `$belongsTo` que é muitos para 1, e dentro dos arrays as configurações:

- *className* = nome da classe que faz as correspondência.
- *foreignKey* = nome da chave estrangeira,

*Existem as convenções padrões, mas, particularmente eu prefiro colocar as minhas.*

**Classes Model:**

```
<?php
//Tabela "Estado" id nomeEstado
class Estado extends AppModel {
    public $name       = 'estado';
    public $useTable   = 'estado';      
    public $primaryKey = 'id';      
    public $hasMany = array('Cidade' => array('className' => 'Cidade','foreignKey' => 'idEstado'));
}
```

---

```
<?php
//Tabela "Cidade" id idEstado (que busca da tabela estado) nomeCidade
class Cidade extends AppModel {
    public $name       = 'cidade';
    public $useTable   = 'cidade';      
    public $primaryKey = 'id';      
    public $belongsTo = array('Estado' => array('className' => 'Estado', 'foreignKey' => 'idEstado'));
    public $hasMany = array('Participante' => array('className' => 'Participante','foreignKey' => 'idCidade'));
}
```

---

```
<?php
//Tabela "Participante" id Nome id_Cidade
class Participante extends AppModel {
    public $name       = 'participante';
    public $useTable   = 'participante';        
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $belongsTo = array('Cidade' => array('className' => 'Cidade', 'foreignKey' => 'idCidade'));
}
```

Teste gerados com as classes obtiveram êxito com o código e figuras logo abaixo:

```
foreach($this->Estado->find('all') as $row){
    printf('<p>%s %s</p>', $row['Estado']['id'],$row['Estado']['nomeEstado']);
}

foreach($this->Cidade->find('all') as $row){
    printf('<p>%s  %s  %s %s</p>', $row['Cidade']['id'],
                           $row['Cidade']['nomeCidade'],
                           $row['Estado']['id'],
                           $row['Estado']['nomeEstado']);
}

//var_dump($this->Participante->find('all'));
foreach($this->Participante->find('all') as $row){
    printf('<p>%s %s %s  %s</p>', 
                           $row['Participante']['id'],
                           $row['Participante']['nome'],
                           $row['Cidade']['id'],
                           $row['Cidade']['nomeCidade']);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Em relação a sua dúvida deve-se montar um variável do tipo `array` com as opções como código abaixo:

```
$options = array('joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'estado',
            'alias' => 'Estado',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('Estado.id = Cidade.idEstado'))
    ),                        
    'fields' => array('Participante.*', 'Cidade.*', 'Estado.*')                        
);   

foreach($this->Participante->find('all', $options) as $row){
    printf('<p>%s %s %s  %s %s</p>', 
                           $row['Participante']['id'],
                           $row['Participante']['nome'],
                           $row['Cidade']['id'],
                           $row['Cidade']['nomeCidade'],
                           $row['Estado']['nomeEstado']);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse [***link***](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-use-join-for-any-relationship-types-in-cakephp) existem mais exemplos.